# Ninject scoping - use same instance across entire graph being constructed

Tags: inversion-of-control, ninject

Let's say I have the following classes that I want to construct using Ninject, with the arrows showing dependencies.

```
A > B > D
A > C > D
```

I want to configure Ninject such that A is transient scoped, i.e. every time you ask Ninject for an A, you get a new one.  I also want B and C to be transient, you get a new one of those every time you ask for an A.  But I want the *D* to be reused across both B and C.  So every time I request an A, I want Ninject to construct one of each object, not two Ds.  But I don't want Ds to be reused across different As.

What is the best way to set this up using Ninject?

**Update:**
After some more research, it seems like Unity has a PerResolveLifetimeManager which does what I'm looking for.  Is there a Ninject equivalent?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ninject supports four built in [object scopes out of the box](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes): Transient, Singleton, Thread, Request.

So there isn't any `PerResolveLifetimeManager` like scope but you can implement it easily with registering a custom scope with the `InScope` method.

As it turned out there is an existing Ninject extension: [`ninject.extensions.namedscope`](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.namedscope) which provides the `InCallScope` method which is what you are looking for.

However if you want to do it yourself you can do with a custom `InScope` delegate. Where you can use the main `IRequest` object for the type `A` to use it as the scope object:

```cs
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind<A>().ToSelf().InTransientScope();
kernel.Bind<B>().ToSelf().InTransientScope();
kernel.Bind<C>().ToSelf().InTransientScope();
kernel.Bind<D>().ToSelf().InScope(
    c =>
        {
            //use the Request for A as the scope object                         
            var requestForA = c.Request;
            while (requestForA != null && requestForA.Service != typeof (A))
            {
                requestForA = requestForA.ParentRequest;
            }
            return requestForA;
        });

var a1 = kernel.Get<A>();    
Assert.AreSame(a1.b.d, a1.c.d);

var a2 = kernel.Get<A>();    
Assert.AreSame(a2.b.d, a2.c.d);

Assert.AreNotSame(a1.c.d, a2.c.d);
```

Where the sample classes are:

```cs
public class A
{
    public readonly B b;
    public readonly C c;
    public A(B b, C c) { this.b = b; this.c = c; }
}

public class B
{
    public readonly D d;
    public B(D d) { this.d = d; }
}

public class C
{
    public readonly D d;  
    public C(D d) { this.d = d; }
}

public class D { }
```

Comment: Won't that break if D is also part if a dependency chain that doesn't include A?

Comment: @KevinBabcock. No it won't break. Then the delegate will return `null` which is equivalent with the following registration: `kernel.Bind<D>().ToSelf().InTransientScope();`

Comment: @nemesv.  This is a good answer, if I want to specify the binding from A down the graph.  But in this case I have many potentials As, and only one D.  So I want to specify the "special" binding for D and not for each A.  I found the solution, which is InCallScope from ninject.extensions.namedscope.  But this is a viable alternative so I will accept the answer.

Comment: @RationalGeek I haven't know about the ninject.extensions.namedscope so +1. But if you check the [source code](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.namedscope/blob/master/src/Ninject.Extensions.NamedScope/NamedScopeExtensionMethods.cs) the  `InCallScope` internally uses very similar logic what I've described in my answer.

Comment: Please don't use that code. While it works for resolve this will cause a memory leak. All the objects will never be released. InCallScope uses a weak reference internally to overcome that problem.

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution to my specific problem, which is InCallScope that is provided by the  [ninject.extensions.namedscope](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.namedscope) extension.  This behaves identically to the Unity PerResolveLifetimeManager concept.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to construct the dependencies yourself.

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind<A>().ToMethod(ctx =>
{
    var d = new D();
    var c = new C(d);
    var b = new B(d);
    var a = new A(b, c);
    return a;
});
```

This may not be the preferred method, but it will always construct a new instance of `A` using a new instance of `B`, `C`, and `D` (but reusing the same instance of `D` for `B` and `C`). You can add a call to `InTransientScope()`, but that is not required as it is the default scope.

Comment: This is far too specific for what I need.  There are actually many different classes at the A, B, C levels in my code that all need to share a D for a given resolution.